# `git checkout [other-branch] path-to-file` does not overwrite file on current branch

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

I am trying to checkout files from a different branch.

I'm using the command

git checkout other-branch path-to-file

for example:

```
git checkout hiresnetworkbug Leaflet-Localized/SpeciesViewController.*
```

However this does nothing to the file on my current branch. I tried to force it with -f option but that didn't work.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that it doesn't update the file in your working tree?  (Your branch would technically be unaffected by `checkout`; the branch is updated when you `commit` changes.)  Does the command produce any output?

Comment: ah good point! My working tree is not updated. The command does not produce any output

Comment: and when I run git status after check out, it says that none of my files have changed

Comment: (1) Are you on Windows, or not, and if on Windows, are you using bash, or PowerShell, or cmd.exe, or what shell? (2) What files, specifically, does `Leaflet-Localized/SpeciesViewController.*` match, in the *current work-tree*? Are the missing files ones that aren't *in* the current work-tree?

Comment: If I understand correctly: 1. I'm on mac 2. SpeciesViewController.* matches SpeciesViewController.m and SpeciesViewController.h in current work-tree. Though now I explicitly add each file. The files aren't missing in either branch (each branch has a copy of each file, and the current work tree has the file), but the file on the current working tree doesn't get updated

Answer (score 0):

The command you show worked for me. The changes were checked out and added to my current index, ready to commit. The only problem I had was that the wild card only picked up files that already existed, since it's expanded by the shell, not by Git.

So in a hypothetical scenario where branch `dev.featureA` has modified versions of `src/a.py` and `src/b.py`, and new file `src/c.py`, doing

```
git checkout dev.featureA src/*.py
```

gave me `src/a.py` and `src/b.py` as modified and ready to commit.

I had to also do

```
git checkout dev.featureA src/c.py
```

to get `src/c.py` added and ready to commit.

Comment: Even if I explicitly add the files (full name), it still doesn't update the working tree (these files exist in both branches)

Comment: The behaviour you observe is weird. Can you show more details like the output of `git status` before and after the checkout, and maybe `git diff --stat hiresnetworkbug Leaflet-Localized/SpeciesViewController.*` and `git diff --stat HEAD Leaflet-Localized/SpeciesViewController.*` before and after the checkout? I'm grasping at straws, I know, but I'm hoping there's something subtle someone might spot in those logs.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is likely the wildcard. It is expanded by your shell before the git executable even starts. Try quoting your path (Both double and single quotes should work; Windows requires double quotes):

```
git checkout hiresnetworkbug -- 'Leaflet-Localized/SpeciesViewController.*'
```

This will update the file in the [working tree *and* in the index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203). Running `git diff` will not show you any differences. `git diff --cached` will and `git status` will also show that the file was modified and staged for commit.